# Which questions are being externally linked to the most?

Tags: support, questions, google, hyperlinks, seo

Is there a way to see a list of which questions are the most linked to from external sources?  There should be some type of Google query that does this.

I'm curious how Superuser is doing now that it's being indexed.  I'd like to see which questions generate traffic and maybe learn something about wording and formatting that will help the site.

There could be feedback left on the linking sites that we could use to improve the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is an easy way to do this. I would suggest however that a relatively accurate analog would be questions with the most up votes.